# Save Countdowntimer on activity destroy and resume it in onResume()

Tags: android, counter, countdowntimer

I want to start a counter for 2 minute and when activity destroy then i want to save that and on activity resume i want to start the counter where i left

```
counter = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            textview.setText("" + String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

            Log.i(TAG, "onTick: "+millisUntilFinished);
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            textview.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Implement  ondestroy method to store your data in shared preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just save a value of `millisUntilFinished` when activity is destroy and create new `CountDownTimer` with that value when activity start again.

```
long millisUntilFinished;
```

in `onDestroy()` (or `onStop()`)

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putLong("millisUntilFinished", millisUntilFinished);
        editor.apply();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

and get value of `millisUntilFinished` when you want to start the `CountDownTimer`

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        millisUntilFinished = prefs.getLong("millisUntilFinished", 120000);

        counter = new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                this.millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
                textview.setText("" + String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
                                - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

                Log.i(TAG, "onTick: " + millisUntilFinished);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textview.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Also note prashant17's answer! onDestroy() isn't necessarily called e.g. when you close the app by pressing the home button

Comment: @DominicM because I don't know about the business of app, it's depend on what is you want. But I have note that is using in onDestroy() (or onStop())

Answer (score 2):

Store your counter data in shared prefrences in `onStop` method as `onDestroy()` is not always guaranteed and start your counter using your stored data from `onResume` method